# Scrolling Issue on SSD1306

Tags: c, horizontal-scrolling

I have downloaded a standard software for sending I2C data to an SSD1306 128 x 64 display for the purpose of understanding how this works.

Most of the routines work as expected but I am facing issues with the scrolling functions of this chip.

The program writes some text to the screen and then calls the below routine with start_row = 0 and end_row = 7

What is actually happening with this code is that page 0 of the display scrolls properly but the rest remains fixed.
The below routine matches well with the description outlined in the ssd1306 data sheet.

However to get all pages to scroll I had to change the 4th WRITECOMMAND to send 6 or 7 instead of 0 for all the text to scroll. Both numbers worked probably because Page7 of the display is empty.In fact changing this number from 0 to 7 has the effect of enabling the equivalent number of Pages to scroll which goes against the description given in the datasheet itself.

Conversely, changing the values of start_row and end_row seemed to alter only the scrolling speed.

It seems that the intent of these parameters is inverted!!!

any explanation please?

```
void SSD1306_ScrollRight(uint8_t start_row, uint8_t end_row)
{
  SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND (SSD1306_RIGHT_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);  // send 0x26
  SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND (0x00);  // send dummy
  SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(start_row);  // start page address
  SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0X00);  // time interval 5 frames
  SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(end_row);  // end page address
  SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0X00);
  SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0XFF);
  SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND (SSD1306_ACTIVATE_SCROLL); // start scroll
}
```

xuraax